# Incorrect name on W-2

Tags: united-states, income-tax, form-w-2

In one of my W-2 forms my first name has been mispelled by a character. However, all other information is correct including my SSN. Do I still request a W-2c from my employer or can I go ahead and file my taxes using the W-2 form with my first name mispelled.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

From [the instructions for Form W-2 (and W-2c)](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/iw2w3.pdf):

> **Correcting an employee's name and/or SSN only.**
>
> If you are correcting only an employee's name and/or SSN,
> complete Form W-2c boxes d through i. Do not complete
> boxes 1 through 20. Advise your employee to correct the
> SSN and/or name on his or her original Form W-2.

That implies that a name-only error warrants a W-2c. The part about "advise the employee to correct the SSN and/or name on his or her original Form W-2" implies that you don't need to wait for the W-2c before you can file. Rather, you can correct the name error yourself on your original W-2 and use that when you file. As long as the SSN is correct, everything should match up.

#### Summary

- Request a W2-c from your employer.
- Correct your name on your original W-2.
- File with the corrected original if the W2-c doesn't arrive in time.

Answer (score 2):

The advice I've seen most commonly is to go ahead and file, but request a corrected W-2 for your records (and so it's right next time). An obvious name typo on a W-2 shouldn't stop your return from being accepted.

In most tax software you can't replicate the name typo as it pre-fills the name, don't worry about it not matching the incorrect W-2, use your correct name.